# Ordered Dithering 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 Matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm looking at the Wiki page here for the Ordered Dithering algorithm and having trouble figuring out how to generate my own map:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering

[Ordered Dithering Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcBFT.png)

My understanding of Matrices is a bit limited I'm still learning on my free time, but what I've gone through doesn't cover equations like this. If I were setting this up as pseudocode in a C# or Python type language, what are my values for Mn and M2n? Do I calculate that same 2x2 matrix left to right as I move through rows?

I see the pseudocode regarding bit arithmetic, but was just curious as to how to set this up in the standard way with multiplication and addition.

Comment: $M_n$ and $M_{2n}$ are square dithering matrices of size $n$ and $2n$ respectively.  What it's explaining there is how to, given a particular-sized matrix, make a larger one.

Comment: That was it, thank you!